# Simultaneous asynchronous API call

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a Windows application which must make an API call exactly 20 times every second.

The requirement is that the reads must be done very CLOSE TO SIMULTANEOUSLY (within milliseconds).

The following code uses a timer that runs every second.  aaList is a list containing 20 objects.

With the current code I have, unfortunately, some reads are done at different times (half a second later sometimes) so obviously a bottleneck is forming somewhere.

Can anyone suggest how my requirements can be achieved in a more simultaneous manner?  (Perhaps I should be doing this in a different way?)

```
private void tmrAAProcess_Tick(object state)
{

     foreach (aa in aaList) {
          Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
          {                       
             aa.ReadFromWebsite();
          }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

     }

}
```

Comment: Exactly 20 times every second? That's every 50 ms, with windows not being a real time operating system, this won't be possible.

Comment: Well they would not run every 50ms...20 calls would need to be made at the same time every second simultaneously.

Comment: I think you will need to measure what exactly is taking that long. Is it starting the threads? Or actually making the requests? Are (some of) the requests to the same server? Have you tried using [`Barrier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx) to synchronize the threads?

Comment: Also, could you explain why do you need to do this? I can't think of any good reason for something like that.

Comment: Heh...sounds like you're trying to make a stress tester for a web site...

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the starting of the threads that takes the time - perhaps when the memory is low on the pc.  The requests are to the same server..it doesn't matter how long it takes after it hits the server as long as all 20 requests get to the server around the same time.

The reason behind it is that the api provider charges for more than 20 hits to the server in every second.  I want to maximise  the number of api calls without getting charged for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely problem is that the [ServicePointManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx) defaults to allowing only two concurrent connections to the same site. You'll have to change the `DefaultConnectionLimit` property, for one.

Another problem is that the TPL is going to limit your parallelism. I don't know what your `ReadFromWebsite` method does, but if it's making a blocking call (i.e. `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse`), it's likely that you'll just end up with a bunch of queued tasks.

I can't imagine that you'll get a sustained rate of 50 ms per request. Communication time alone will probably exceed that unless it's an in-house server. Your machine will run out of connections after a while, because it's waiting on responses. Either that or you'll run out of memory with all those queued tasks.

If you want to make this work, you'll have to at least:

1. Modify the `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`
2. Make asynchronous web requests
3. Explicitly limit the number of concurrent outstanding requests using a queue or a semaphore or something similar.

You should keep a running average of the response time for the last N (some reasonably small number like 20) requests, and not make requests faster than that.

Comment: Thank you.  You pointed me in the right direction.  ReadFromWebsite() was indeed synchronous.  I changed that to be asynchronous so that I would not need to open a new thread.  Hence I was able to remove the Task.Factory.StartNew call.  I already had the defaultconnectionlimit set.  So now it is a lot quicker given that new threads are not being created.  It is not exactly simultaneous but it is good enough for my needs.